# Apache MQ - JMS message selector

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I need some help to fetch all the messages for a particular queue which has a particular property on it.

The problem here is I need to match the JMS header property **process** with **processName**.As the message can have the value for process as upper or lowercase but processName always has a value which is uppercase.

I can **NOT** use equalsIgnorecase here like :
StringJMSCriteriaBuilder("process").equalIgnorecase(processName);

As there is no such method in IJMSSelectorCriteriaBuilder  interface.

Below is the code I have currently:

```
private String createJMSSelectorMessage(QueueFilter queueFilter) throws Exception {
        StringBuffer selectorMessage = new StringBuffer();
        String processName=Service.getProcess(Long.valueOf(queueFilter.getProcess())).getProcessName();


        IJMSSelectorCriteriaBuilder processNameSelectorCriteriaBuilder = new StringJMSCriteriaBuilder("process").eq(processName);
        selectorMessage.append(processNameSelectorCriteriaBuilder.getJMSSelectorCriteriaValue());
        return selectorMessage;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMS specification [stipulates](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html) that selectors are case sensitive.

> Two strings are equal if and only if they contain the same sequence of characters.

Solutions I have seen used include:

- Pre-processing all messages to normalize case
- Use Message Broker
- Browse, evaluate in code and select
- Have the program putting the message normalize case first

Sorry, there's no good receiver-side solution that doesn't involve parsing every message.