# Is it possible to make JMS selector case insensitive?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, camel-sql

I know that the JMS headers properties are case sensitive. But I am working on one requirement where I have to make JMS selctor to not case sensitive. Is it possible to do so?
I am using camel and below is the way I am defining my selector in properties file.

accountQueue = ActiveMQqueueJmsComponent:queue:account?selector=money <> ('Dollar')

Camel route :

```
@Value("${consumer.accountQueue}")
   private String accountQueue;


@Bean
   RouteBuilder accountRouteBuilder() {
      return new RouteBuilder() {

         @Override
         public void configure() throws Exception {

            from(accountQueue).to(OrderService)
            }
            }
        }
```

I tried to use function like UPPER and LOWER but not able to get success. I am defing like below.

```
accountQueue = ActiveMQqueueJmsComponent:queue:account?selector=money <> UPPER('Dollar')  // not working
```

Comment: [Article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969274/apache-mq-jms-message-selector) might help you to resolve your query.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the function calls in selector enhancement that was added to ActiveMQ in [this JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3097).  Using this enhancement you might be able to craft something that fits your needs.

This enhancement allow for some custom function calls to be made with a few built in functions as follows:

```
    Message message = createMessage();
    assertSelector(message, "REGEX('1870414179', SessionserverId)", false);
    message.setLongProperty("SessionserverId", 1870414179);
    assertSelector(message, "REGEX('1870414179', SessionserverId)", true);
    assertSelector(message, "REGEX('[0-9]*', SessionserverId)", true);
    assertSelector(message, "REGEX('^[1-8]*$', SessionserverId)", false);
    assertSelector(message, "REGEX('^[1-8]*$', SessionserverId)", false);

    assertSelector(message, "INLIST(SPLIT('Tom,Dick,George',','), name)", false);
    assertSelector(message, "INLIST(SPLIT('Tom,James,George',','), name)", true);

    assertSelector(message, "INLIST(MAKELIST('Tom','Dick','George'), name)", false);
    assertSelector(message, "INLIST(MAKELIST('Tom','James','George'), name)", true);

    assertSelector(message, "REGEX('connection1111', REPLACE(JMSMessageID,':',''))", true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Bish for reply. however I used below syntax but no luck so far. ActiveMQqueueJmsComponent:queue:account?selector=money <> '"REGEX(^[\p{DOLLAR}\p{dollar} ._-]*$)"'.                                           I think the link you post which is to make customize/apply function on selector while publishing. But I am looking for regex while subscription scenario. Below is the way I am subscribing from queue(also shown in question).